# Did Einstein write a brilliant discovery with coal?

Tags: albert-einstein

My philosophy teacher told us this, that Albert Einstein in his late years was outside one day, and was suddenly struck by inspiration for something important (perhaps the unifying theory of physics, no less). Having no paper and no pen, he looked how he could write down this marvellous idea so as not to forget it. Nearby, there was a coal delivery truck, and so Einstein picked up a lump of coal and wrote his idea on the side of the truck. The truck driver refused to put up with him and drove off and the idea was lost forever.

Is that even remotely true?

Comment: Close enough for philosphy instruction!